# Android Splash Screen with Web View

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, splash-screen

I have read a article to create a splash screen from
https://android.jlelse.eu/launch-screen-in-android-the-right-way-aca7e8c31f52

I have already created the androidmanifest.xml for my WebView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mobileapps.mysite">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.mobileapps.mysite.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Now how I have to add the following code to the above code.

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
  android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

the code for styles.xml is

```
<resources>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: It seems like your `<activity android:name="com.mobileapps.mysite.MainActivity"` is missing `android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"`

Answer (score 0):

Full code in your manifest should be like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mobileapps.mysite">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.mobileapps.mysite.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I got a error as C:\Users\myname\AndroidStudioProjects\mysite\New\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-21:20: AAPT: error: resource style/SplashTheme (aka com.mobileapps.mysite:style/SplashTheme) not found. I have updated my question with the styles.xml.

Comment: My bad. `android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">` should be `android:theme="@styles/SplashTheme">` try it

Comment: Now I got the error as - C:\Users\myname\AndroidStudioProjects\mysite\New\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-21:20: AAPT: error: '@styles/SplashTheme' is incompatible with attribute theme (attr) reference.

Comment: Sorry `@styles` should be `@style`. But couldn't figure out what is that error